# .NET MVC4 application cannot run due to MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Yesterday I installed the `MySql 5.7`,and it contains MySql connector/net. But today when I run an MVC4 application, an error occurs. The server shows that cannot find dll `MySql.Web.v20, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d`, or system could not find this file.

The machine.config has been changed by mysql installer in some sections like `MySQLMembershipProvider` and `MySQLRoleProvider`.

Could you tell me what is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just a dll version and/or PublicKeyToken mismatch. Just remove the reference to MySql Connector dll, and add it again.

If the error persists, look the properties of this dll, get its PublicKeyToken, search for the xml code that points to this reference (I can't remember where right now, but You'll be able to find easily with the find tool of Visual Studio) and set every property to match with this new dll You've installed.

(It's a very good thing make a backup (or even a simple Ctrl+C > Ctrl+V > Comment) before any of this changes)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is somehow stupid as hell but it works like a charm (at least in my case).

As you can see it is looking for something called "MySql.Web.v20.dll". It would be completely normal that "MySql.Web.v20.dll" = "MySql.Web.dll" but it is not.

Take a look in this folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies"

in there I have 4 folders, RT, v2.0, v4.0 nad v4.5. When you look at any of them you will see that all of them contain files named MySql.Web.dll, but only folder v2.0 contains MySql.Web.v20.dll.

Now take a look at VS Reference Manager. In the filter type in mysql and a result is quite interesing. I personally have 5 MySql.Web entries. When you hold your mouse over each one it will show you the absolute path to that reference. Only one of them all is actually MySql.Web.v20.dll.

It fixes problems for me. But i would like to know why and how that works. Cheers.